# Evaluate a String in PHP

Tags: php, eval

Well. I'm having a problem with the eval(); function in PHP. I don't quite understand how to store the returned data into a variable to print.. my code is as follows:

```
<?php 
    $a = 4; 
    $write = eval("$a+$a;"); 
    echo $write; 
?>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I run the PHP script, all it does is output nothing..
Any help is appreciated

Comment: *"The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged."* http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Yeah I know -- I just want to know how to use it in case I **need** it for a later time. I tried a few different revisions of this.. none worked. I'm learning PHP right now, so I'm trying to get as much information on it's functions and whatnot as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/eval):

> **eval()** returns **`NULL`** unless ***return*** is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to ***return*** is returned.

Answer (score 0):

try `eval("\$write = \$a+\$a;")`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $a = 4;
    eval("\$write = \$a+\$a;");
    var_dump($write); 
?>
```

It will return **int(8)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $a = 4; 
    $write = eval("return $a+$a;"); 
    echo $write; 
?>
```

Comment: you should always include explanation and background info on the solution you propose